# How to ignore an error after catching it and execute final result in rxjs forkJoin?

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, fork-join

```
   myfunc() { 
        const combined = forkJoin(

            this.service.fn1(parameter).pipe(
                catchError(err => {
                   throw (this.handleError(err));
                }),
            ),

            this.service2.fn2().pipe(
                catchError(err => 
                //i need to ignore this error and execute final result,
            ), 

            this.service3.fn3().pipe(
                catchError(err => // Need to ignore this error too and continue)
            ));

         const subscribe = combined.subscribe (
            ([fn1,fn2,fn3]) => {

               //execute this part even if fn2, fn3 call fails. How can i do ??     

          }    
     );
}
```

How  can i ignore  the error which i catch in service2.fn2() and service3.fn3() and execute the final part?

I'm new to this and any help would be appreciated.

I saw this link but i didn't understand completely. If anyone can tell in simple terms it would be great.

http://jsbin.com/babirakiyi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: just return `empty()` in `catchError` like this for example: `catchError(() => empty())`

Comment: don't throw a error inside the catch error

Comment: @martin if i add empty(), it is not executing the final result part!

Comment: @Ricardo I need to show different output for function 1 , so i'm throwing and performing some action there. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the subscription method accept 3 functions parameters as you can see in his implementation

```
subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
```

use the second one to handle your error

**UPDATED**

your function will look like

```
myfunc() { 
const combined = forkJoin(
    this.service.fn1(parameter),
    this.service2.fn2(),
    this.service3.fn3())   

  const subscribe = combined.subscribe (
        ([fn1,fn2,fn3]) => {
           //execute this part even if fn2, fn3 call fails. How can i do ??     
      }, (err)=>{
          // here you can manage the side effect action
      }    
 );
}
```

the second function will be executed if a error is throw

**UDPATED #2**

if you want to handle the errors independently you can catch each one

```
       const combined = forkJoin(
        this.service.fn1(parameter).catch((err)=>{ 
        // do your side effect 
        return Observable.of(undefined) 
        }),
        this.service2.fn2().catch(/** same idea*/),
        this.service3.fn3().catch(/** same idea*/))
```

notice you will receive undefined on the subscription array for each observable that fails

Comment: I appreciate your help. As i said, i'm new to this can you please add this in my example and show how can i implement that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing, But That's the common error handler for all three apis right. I need to handle differently for first case and the next two should be handled differently :/